# Raising an exception with pytest not working as expected

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests, mocking, pytest

I have a function that makes an http request and throws an error if the response is not a 200. It looks like this:

```py
def put_request(param1, param2):
    url = f"api/v1/some/route"
    response = requests.put(
        url,
        json=param2,
        verify="test",
    )

    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise CustomError()

    return response.json()
```

I want to test that the exception is correct so my test code looks like:

```py
def test_put_request_error(mocker):
    requests_mock = mocker.patch("path.to.file.requests")
    requests_mock.put.return_value.status_code = 500

    with pytest.raises(CustomError) as error:
        put_request(param1=param1, param2={some data})
        
    assert error.value.code == 500
```

Problem is, the error gets raise in the code gets raised and execution stops. It never makes it back to the assertion in the my test. I could use some advice on fixing this!

This pattern seems to work for my other test cases so I'm not sure what the problem here is!

EDIT: The issue was in the imports! The imports from my tests needed to be the same from my actual code. This means both need to be absolute or relative!

Comment: Are you sure that `CustomError` is raised and not some other exception? Can you show the test output? 
Also, are you sure that the imported `CustomError` is the same as the raised one (these could be different references).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Yes this error is being returned. The error is expected in the output: 

models.exceptions.CustomError: Could not create db instance. Error: <MagicMock name='requests.put().json()' id='5232268480'>

Comment: Please add the test output to the question, not to the comment, and also please show how you import the exception in the code and the test.

Comment: @TurmoiledPython If you have resolved your question, please write a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was in the imports. After [MrBean Bremen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12480730/mrbean-bremen) asked to show the imports, I realized my code used relative paths and my test used absolute paths. When I made these both the same they worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with a formatted code snippet showing how you fixed the import statements - e.g. did you make them both absolute or both relative?

Comment: Yes, would be super helpful